# how to get the documents associated with projects or issues from atTask api

Tags: attask

am new to attask api.
Am trying to get the documents associated with the projects or tasks  from atTask using api, where exactly i will find the relationship between projects and documents. I mean in which table i will find this relation in Relational Databases provided by atTask API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the Document of a task or poject you would need to supply the Project ID or Task ID reffer to the API document at https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/.

An example getting all documents in a project would be

[domain].attask-ondemand.com/attask/api/DOCU?projectID=XXXXXXXXXXXX