# how to get the documents from attask

Tags: attask

Am new to atTask .
My work is to pull the documents from atTask server.
Can you share me the sample code(c# or Java) to get the documents associated with the projects or issues  from atTask?

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>(); 
map.put("groupID", user.getString("homeGroupID"));   
JSONArray results = client.search("proj", map, new String[]{"ID", "name", "plannedStartDate", "hasDocuments", "projectID", "portfolioID", "groupID", "extRefID", "URL"});
```

Here am able to get the group id , project id...etc but my requirement is to get the documents associated with each project. can you help on this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("groupID", user.getString("homeGroupID"));   
JSONArray results = client.search("proj", map, new String[]{"ID", "name", "plannedStartDate", "hasDocuments", "projectID", "portfolioID", "groupID", "extRefID", "URL"}); here am able to get the group id , project id...etc but my requirement is to get the documents associated with each project. can you help on this?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24553648/how-to-get-the-documents-associated-with-projects-or-issues-from-attask-api

Answer (score 0):

the API docs are available on

https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/api-explorer/

https://developers.attask.com/api-docs/code-samples/

They can fetch the data for u , or can use the POSTMAN plugin of chrome browser to send the rest call to the AtTask server with Get, Post req.